# Run Protractor e2e Test script Using Task Scheduler – Windows 10

Tags: angular, protractor, angular6, windows-task-scheduler

I have Protractor E2E test for our application, now want to run it on windows  machine/server using windows 'Task Scheduler', did anyone have knowledge about how to configure 'Task Scheduler'?

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you have to follow step in the given [link for configuring task scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10)

Second part is that you have to create batch file that would run as a part of task scheduler. Following is the commands you can save in notepad and save it as *.bat extension. These command runs the sample spec files of protractor.

```
c:\
cd %appdata%\npm\node_modules\protractor\example
start protractor conf.js
```

Note: You will have to ensure that protractor is installed globally before running batch file in task scheduler. You can also create batch file referring to your test automation.